# end click button to start of index, and start of index to end of index

Tags: javascript, html, css

how so that when at the end of the index, the index returns to 0 (by clicking the `.button-forward`).
And how when it is at the beginning of index [0], it will return to the last index (by clicking the `.back-button)`.
This is the full code:

```js
"use strict"; {
  const daftarSlider = document.querySelector(".daftar-slider");
  const itemSlider = document.querySelectorAll(".item-slider");
  const tombolMaju = document.querySelector(".tombol-maju");
  const tombolMundur = document.querySelector(".tombol-mundur");
  let jumlahItems;
  let indeksItem;
  const mediaQueryList = [window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)"), window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)"), ];
  const tampilkanItems = () => {
    let html = "";
    let len = indeksItem + jumlahItems;
    for (let i = indeksItem; i < len; i++) {
      html += itemSlider[i].outerHTML;
    }
    daftarSlider.innerHTML = html;
  };
  const HandleScreen = () => {
    if (mediaQueryList[0].matches) {
      jumlahItems = 1;
      indeksItem = 0;
      itemSlider.forEach((item) => {
        item.style.width = "100%";
        item.style.minHeight = "400px";
      });
    } else if (mediaQueryList[1].matches) {
      jumlahItems = 2;
      indeksItem = 0;
      itemSlider.forEach((item) => {
        item.style.width = "50%";
        item.style.minHeight = "400px";
      });
    } else {
      jumlahItems = 3;
      indeksItem = 0;
      itemSlider.forEach((item) => {
        item.style.width = "35%";
        item.style.minHeight = "400px";
      });
    }
    tampilkanItems();
  };
  HandleScreen();
  for (let i = 0; i < mediaQueryList.length; i++) {
    mediaQueryList[i].addListener(HandleScreen);
  }
  tombolMaju.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (indeksItem < itemSlider.length - jumlahItems) {
      indeksItem++;
      tampilkanItems();
    }
  });
  tombolMundur.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (indeksItem > 0) {
      indeksItem--;
      tampilkanItems();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.slider-container {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: auto;
}

.daftar-slider {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-slider:not(.item-slider:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.item-slider {
  background-color: gray;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.item-slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.slider-arrows {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <ul class="daftar-slider">
    <li class="item-slider">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="gambar/1.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-slider">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="gambar/2.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-slider">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="gambar/3.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-slider">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="gambar/4.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-slider">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="gambar/5.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-slider">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="gambar/6.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-slider">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="gambar/7.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-slider">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="gambar/8.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-slider">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="gambar/9.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-slider">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="gambar/10.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-slider">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="gambar/11.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-slider">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="gambar/12.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="slider-arrows">
    <button type="button" class="tombol-mundur">Sebelumnya</button>
    <button type="button" class="tombol-maju">Selanjutnya</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

the code runs correctly. It's just that I want to add infinite shift.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is to maintain an index of the button you're currently on, and use that to show the "active" button.

This example doesn't match your code but should give you a better understanding of how it works.

```js
// Cache your < and > buttons, and your number elements
const directions = document.querySelectorAll('.direction');
const numbers= document.querySelectorAll('.number');

// Add event listeners to your direction buttons
// `handleClick` returns a new function maintaining the
// index which it updates
directions.forEach(direction => {
  direction.addEventListener('click', handleClick(), false)
});

function handleClick() {
  
  // Initialise the index
  let index = 0;
  
  // Return a function to the listener
  return function (e) {
    
    // Get the direction from the button's dataset
    const { direction } = e.target.dataset;

    // Remove the class from the previous button
    numbers[index].classList.remove('active');

    // Work out what the new index needs to be
    if (direction === 'previous') {
      if (index === 0) {
        index = numbers.length - 1;
      } else {
        --index;
      }
    } else {
      if (index === numbers.length - 1) {
        index = 0;
      } else {
        ++index;
      }
    }

    // Update the new button
    numbers[index].classList.add('active');

  }
  
}
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<button data-direction="previous" class="direction"><</button>
<button class="number active">1</button>
<button class="number">2</button>
<button class="number">3</button>
<button class="number">4</button>
<button class="number">5</button>
<button data-direction="forward" class="direction">></button>
```

Comment: I'll try, boss. I've been learning javascript for more than 1 year but I'm still confused.